# Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

Tags: jquery, base-de-datos, firebase, backend

holaa
estoy usando firebase en mi app web para usar la base de datos en tiempo real. También estoy usando jquery en mi archivo js, el cual esta así:

```
//LOGIN
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
$('#login').click(function(){
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.user);
        $('#login').hide();
        $('#root').append("<img src='"+result.user.photoURL+"' />")
    });
});

//escribir en la base de datos
$('#guardar').click(function(){
    firebase.database().ref("usuarios")
    .set({
        nombre: "david",
        apellido: "gonzalez",
        puntos: "20 puntos"
    });
});
```

pero cuando apreto guardar para enviar el objeto a mi base de datos me sale este error: 
Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function

que creen que podria ser?? graciass

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi!!
si tienes el mismo problema, lo que hice fue agregar una librería que me faltaba, la cual se encuentra acá, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-bower
hay que ver la versión del archivo de database y copiar este script en nuestro archivo html:

en este caso es la versión 7.14.1   pero hay que cambiarla en el caso de que en el link de github se vea que haya otra versión.